# Tensorflow 1.14.0 C API TF_SessionRun memory leak

Tags: python, c, tensorflow

I'm using Tensorflow 1.14.0 C API precompiled binaries from [official site](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c) on Windows for semantic segmentation. I have trained model in python using [this repo](https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models) and converted it to .pb, loaded model and predict with C API, everything works fine besides memory leak that I find when I ran my code. I tried to figure out the source of memory leak and used heap profiling tool in Visual Studio 2017. The types view of snapshots difference of two predictions shows no new allocations, but in stacks view I find this:

```
Identifier,     Count Diff,  Size Diff, Count,       Size,               Module
ModelPredict            +3  +1 048 735      7   2 097 870   TensorflowModel.dll
     [Unknown Frame]    +3  +1 048 735      7   2 097 870   tensorflow.dll
```

This I find in snapshot from second prediction (this why size is doubled), where TensorflowModel.dll is dll writen by me with this prediction code:

```c
typedef struct model_t {
    TF_Graph* graph;
    TF_Session* session;
    TF_Status* status;

    TF_Output input, target, output;

    TF_Operation *init_op, *train_op, *save_op, *restore_op;
    TF_Output checkpoint_file;
} model_t;

typedef struct NetProperties {
    int width;
    int height;
    int border;
    int classes;
    int inputSize;
} NetProperties;

static void Deallocator(void* data, size_t length, void* arg) {
    free(data);
}

static model_t * model;
static NetProperties * properties;

extern "C" EXPORT int ModelCreate(const char* nnFilename, const char* inputName, const char* outputName, int pictureWidth, int pictureHeight, int border, int classes) {
    ModelDestroy();
    model = (model_t*)malloc(sizeof(model_t));;
    model->status = TF_NewStatus();
    model->graph = TF_NewGraph();
    properties = (NetProperties*)malloc(sizeof(NetProperties));
    properties->width = pictureWidth;
    properties->height = pictureHeight;
    properties->border = border;
    properties->classes = classes;
    properties->inputSize = (pictureWidth + border * 2) * (pictureHeight + border * 2) * 3;
    {
        // Create the session.
        TF_SessionOptions* opts = TF_NewSessionOptions();
        model->session = TF_NewSession(model->graph, opts, model->status);
        TF_DeleteSessionOptions(opts);
        if (!Okay(model->status)) return 0;
    }

    TF_Graph* g = model->graph;

    {
        // Import the graph.
        TF_Buffer* graph_def = read_file(nnFilename);
        if (graph_def == NULL) return 0;
        printf("Read GraphDef of %zu bytes\n", graph_def->length);
        TF_ImportGraphDefOptions* opts = TF_NewImportGraphDefOptions();
        TF_GraphImportGraphDef(g, graph_def, opts, model->status);
        TF_DeleteImportGraphDefOptions(opts);
        TF_DeleteBuffer(graph_def);
        if (!Okay(model->status)) return 0;
    }

    // Handles to the interesting operations in the graph.
    model->input.oper = TF_GraphOperationByName(g, inputName);
    model->input.index = 0;
    model->target.oper = TF_GraphOperationByName(g, "target");
    model->target.index = 0;
    model->output.oper = TF_GraphOperationByName(g, outputName);
    model->output.index = 0;

    model->init_op = TF_GraphOperationByName(g, "init");
    model->train_op = TF_GraphOperationByName(g, "train");
    model->save_op = TF_GraphOperationByName(g, "save/control_dependency");
    model->restore_op = TF_GraphOperationByName(g, "save/restore_all");

    model->checkpoint_file.oper = TF_GraphOperationByName(g, "save/Const");
    model->checkpoint_file.index = 0;

    unsigned char * randomData = (unsigned char*)malloc(properties->inputSize * sizeof(unsigned char));
    for (int i = 0; i < properties->inputSize; i++) {
        randomData[i] = (unsigned char)100;
    }
    ModelPredict(randomData, false, false);
    free(randomData);
    return 1;
}

extern "C" EXPORT void ModelDestroy() {
    if (model == nullptr) return;
    TF_DeleteSession(model->session, model->status);
    Okay(model->status);
    TF_DeleteGraph(model->graph);
    TF_DeleteStatus(model->status);
    free(model);
    free(properties);
}

extern "C" EXPORT unsigned char* ModelPredict(unsigned char * batch, bool needRevertRgb, bool needRevertUpdsideDown) {
    if (model == NULL) return NULL;
    const int64_t dims[4] = { 1, properties->height, properties->width, 3 };
    size_t nbytes = properties->inputSize;

    // can be faster
    float * arrayOfFloats = (float*)malloc(nbytes * sizeof(float));
    float multiplier = 1.0;
    if (needRevertUpdsideDown) {
        for (int i = properties->height + properties->border * 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            int width = (properties->width + properties->border * 2) * 3;
            for (int j = 0; j < properties->width + properties->border * 2; j++) {
                if (needRevertRgb) {
                    arrayOfFloats[i * width + j * 3 + 0] = batch[i * width + j * 3 + 2] * multiplier;
                    arrayOfFloats[i * width + j * 3 + 1] = batch[i * width + j * 3 + 1] * multiplier;
                    arrayOfFloats[i * width + j * 3 + 2] = batch[i * width + j * 3 + 0] * multiplier;
                }
                else {
                    arrayOfFloats[i * width + j * 3 + 0] = batch[i * width + j * 3 + 0] * multiplier;
                    arrayOfFloats[i * width + j * 3 + 1] = batch[i * width + j * 3 + 1] * multiplier;
                    arrayOfFloats[i * width + j * 3 + 2] = batch[i * width + j * 3 + 2] * multiplier;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < properties->height + properties->border * 2; i++) {
            int width = (properties->width + properties->border * 2) * 3;
            for (int j = 0; j < properties->width + properties->border * 2; j++) {
                if (needRevertRgb) {
                    arrayOfFloats[i * width + j * 3 + 0] = batch[i * width + j * 3 + 2] * multiplier;
                    arrayOfFloats[i * width + j * 3 + 1] = batch[i * width + j * 3 + 1] * multiplier;
                    arrayOfFloats[i * width + j * 3 + 2] = batch[i * width + j * 3 + 0] * multiplier;
                }
                else {
                    arrayOfFloats[i * width + j * 3 + 0] = batch[i * width + j * 3 + 0] * multiplier;
                    arrayOfFloats[i * width + j * 3 + 1] = batch[i * width + j * 3 + 1] * multiplier;
                    arrayOfFloats[i * width + j * 3 + 2] = batch[i * width + j * 3 + 2] * multiplier;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    // Optionally, you can check that your input_op and input tensors are correct
    //// by using some of the functions provided by the C API.
    //std::cout << "Input op info: " << TF_OperationNumOutputs(input_op) << "\n";
    //std::cout << "Input data info: " << TF_Dim(input, 0) << "\n";

    std::vector<TF_Output> inputs;
    std::vector<TF_Tensor*> input_values;
    TF_Operation* input_op = model->input.oper;
    TF_Output input_opout = { input_op, 0 };
    inputs.push_back(input_opout);

    TF_Tensor* input = TF_NewTensor(TF_FLOAT, dims, 4, (void*)arrayOfFloats, nbytes * sizeof(float), &Deallocator, NULL);
    input_values.push_back(input);

    int outputSize = properties->width * properties->height * properties->classes;

    int64_t out_dims[] = { 1, properties->height, properties->width, properties->classes };

    // Create vector to store graph output operations
    std::vector<TF_Output> outputs;
    TF_Operation* output_op = model->output.oper;
    TF_Output output_opout = { output_op, 0 };
    outputs.push_back(output_opout);

    // Create TF_Tensor* vector
    //std::vector<TF_Tensor*> output_values(outputs.size(), nullptr);

    // Similar to creating the input tensor, however here we don't yet have the
    // output values, so we use TF_AllocateTensor()
    TF_Tensor* output_value = TF_AllocateTensor(TF_FLOAT, out_dims, 4, outputSize * sizeof(float));
    //output_values.push_back(output_value);

    //// As with inputs, check the values for the output operation and output tensor
    //std::cout << "Output: " << TF_OperationName(output_op) << "\n";
    //std::cout << "Output info: " << TF_Dim(output_value, 0) << "\n";

    TF_SessionRun(model->session, NULL,
        &inputs[0], &input_values[0], inputs.size(),
        &outputs[0], &output_value, outputs.size(),
        /* No target operations to run */
        NULL, 0, NULL, model->status);
    if (!Okay(model->status)) return NULL;
    TF_DeleteTensor(input_values[0]);

    // memory allocations take place here
    //float* prediction = (float*)TF_TensorData(output_value);
    float* prediction = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * outputSize);
    memcpy(prediction, TF_TensorData(output_value), sizeof(float) * outputSize);
    unsigned char * charPrediction = new unsigned char[outputSize * sizeof(unsigned char)];
    for (int i = 0; i < outputSize; i++) {
        charPrediction[i] = (unsigned char)((prediction[i] * 255));
    }
    free(prediction);
    TF_DeleteTensor(output_value);
    return charPrediction;
}
```

This 1048735 bytes are allocated and not freed when code runs `TF_SessionRun`.
For now I don't understand is this my mistake or I should submit issue to tensorflow repo on github.

UPDATE 1:

I find out that the size of leaking memory depends on model. I loaded self-written simple U-Net and the size of leak reduced to 153823 bytes, but still persist after each `TF_SessionRun`. Python code for this model:

```py
def test_unet(pretrained_weights = None,input_size = 284, border=88):
    inputs = Input(((input_size + border * 2) * (input_size + border * 2) * 3,))

    reshape1 = Reshape((input_size + border * 2 , input_size + border * 2, 3))(inputs)
    # 284
    conv0 = Conv2D(64, 3 , activation = 'relu',  kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(reshape1)
    # 282
    conv0 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu',  kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv0)
    # 280
    conv0 = BatchNormalization()(conv0)
    pool0 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv0)

    # 140
    conv1 = Conv2D(128, 3 , activation = 'relu',  kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool0)
    # 138
    conv1 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu',  kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)
    # 136
    conv1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)

    # 68
    conv2 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool1)
    # 66
    conv2 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv2)
    # 64
    conv2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)

    # 32
    conv3 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool2)
    # 30
    conv3 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv3)
    # 28
    conv3 = BatchNormalization()(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)

    # added
    conv3_1 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', padding='same')(pool3)
    conv3_1 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', padding='same')(conv3_1)
    conv3_1 = BatchNormalization()(conv3_1)
    drop1 = Dropout(0.5)(conv3_1)
    up0 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', padding='same')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(drop1))
    up0 = BatchNormalization()(up0)

    # 56
    up1 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(up0))
    up1 = BatchNormalization()(up1)
    # 54
    cropp1 = Cropping2D((5,5))(conv2)
    merge1 = concatenate([cropp1,up1], axis = 3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge1)
    # 52
    #conv4 = BatchNormalization()(conv4)

    # 104
    up2 = Conv2D(128, 2, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv4))
    up2 = BatchNormalization()(up2)
    # 103? wtf

    up2 = Cropping2D(((1,0),(1,0)))(up2)
    cropp2 = Cropping2D((17,17))(conv1)
    merge2 = concatenate([cropp2,up2], axis = 3)
    conv5 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge2)
    # 100
    conv5 = BatchNormalization()(conv5)

    # 200
    up3 = Conv2D(64, 2, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv5))
    up3 = BatchNormalization()(up3)
    # 199
    up3 = Cropping2D(((1,0),(1,0)))(up3)
    cropp3 = Cropping2D((41,41))(conv0)
    merge3 = concatenate([cropp3,up3], axis = 3)
    conv6 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge3)
    # 196
    conv7 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv6)
    reshape2 = Reshape((input_size * input_size,))(conv7)
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=reshape2)

    model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.0001), loss=bce_dice_loss, metrics=[dice_coeff])

    model.summary()

    if(pretrained_weights):
        model.load_weights(pretrained_weights)

    return model
```

UDPATE 2:

I find out what the memory leak is. The size of leak = input_size + output_size + 159. I changed the size of images and noticed that the size of leak depends on input image size. So the original leak is the leak for image 512*512*3 (for rgb) + output 512*512*1 (one class) + mystery 159 bytes = 1048735. For now it looks like I missed some command for session to free passed tensors, `TF_DeleteTensor();` frees the memory but something remain allocated.

Comment: Maybe not related, but I don't see you free `model` and `properties`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie This structures are initialized once at start and used during all predictions, but I have leak on every prediction and this structures less than ~1MB that leaks. Also this functions are called from another code and `ModelDestroy()` that calls `free(model)` is called outside too. Thanks for pointing out that 'NetProperties' is not deallocated, this one I missed but 20 bytes is not the main question.